# Add two data frames based on a column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I have two data frames. One is like below:

```
   D_Time                   Speed_BT       Speed_GT
2016-09-12 00:15:00          23            60  
2016-09-12 00:45:00          13            48  
2016-09-12 01:30:00          13            25
```

The other one is like this:

```
D_Time                     Speed_AA        Speed_DD
2016-09-12 00:30:00          29            17  
2016-09-12 01:00:00          46            59  
2016-09-12 01:30:00          36            51
```

I want to add the two data frames based on `D_Time`. So, it will look like the following table:

```
D_Time                   Speed_BT       Speed_GT    Speed_AA   Speed_DD
2016-09-12 00:15:00          23            60          NA         NA
2016-09-12 00:30:00          NA            NA          29         17
2016-09-12 00:45:00          13            48          NA         NA
2016-09-12 01:00:00          NA            NA          46         59
2016-09-12 01:15:00          NA            NA          NA         NA
2016-09-12 01:30:00          13            25          36         51
```

It will be great if I can add the 5th row like the way I have added in the data frame. However, If there is no other way then its okay.

I already have tried using this command:

```
add <- merge(df1, df2,by = "D_Time", all=TRUE)
```

But, the problem is it does not add properly. `Speed_AA` and `Speed_DD` value add in different rows where the time is different.

```
D_Time class is "POSIXct" "POSIXt".
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the sequence for every 15 minutes first and merge that also with your data frames, i.e.

```
ind <- c(df1$D_Time, df2$D_Time)

df4 <- data.frame(D_Time = seq.POSIXt(min(ind), max(ind), by = '15 mins'), 
                                                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Reduce(function(...)merge(..., all = TRUE), list(df1, df2, df4))
```

Which gives,

> ```
>             D_Time Speed_BT Speed_GT Speed_AA Speed_DD
> 1 2016-09-12 00:15:00       23       60       NA       NA
> 2 2016-09-12 00:30:00       NA       NA       29       17
> 3 2016-09-12 00:45:00       13       48       NA       NA
> 4 2016-09-12 01:00:00       NA       NA       46       59
> 5 2016-09-12 01:15:00       NA       NA       NA       NA
> 6 2016-09-12 01:30:00       13       25       36       51
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Except for the 5th row, the desired output can be acheived by the following:

```
df <- read.table(text="D_Time,Speed_BT,Speed_GT
2016-09-12 00:15:00, 23,  60  
2016-09-12 00:45:00, 13,  48  
2016-09-12 01:30:00, 13,  25", header=TRUE, sep=",")

df2 <- read.table(text="D_Time, Speed_AA,        Speed_DD
2016-09-12 00:30:00,          29,            17  
2016-09-12 01:00:00,          46,            59  
2016-09-12 01:30:00,          36,            51
", header=TRUE, sep=",")

merge(df, df2, all=TRUE)
```

If you want to include the fifth row, it has to be in one of the dataframes either in `df` or in `df2`, If you initialize `df` as shown below and then call `merge(df, df2, all=TRUE)` you will have the fifth row as well.

```
df <- read.table(text="D_Time,Speed_BT,Speed_GT
2016-09-12 00:15:00, 23,  60  
2016-09-12 00:45:00, 13,  48  
2016-09-12 01:30:00, 13,  25
2016-09-12 01:15:00, NA, NA", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Comment: I have used this command as stated in the question. This command is not working for this particular problem. I am not sure, what is wrong here? Just wondering any other way to add these data frame

Comment: can you be specific about what is not working, share an error message, or part of output that is not according to your expectation so that I can alter the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here are two  `data.table` approaches:

#### Multiple right joins

This is more or less the `data.table` version of [Sotos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518980/3817004):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = "D_Time")[setDT(df2, key = "D_Time")[
  .(D_Time = seq(min(df1$D_Time, df2$D_Time),
                 max(df1$D_Time, df2$D_Time), by = "15 mins"))]]
```

> ```
>                 D_Time Speed_BT Speed_GT Speed_AA Speed_DD
> 1: 2016-09-12 00:15:00       23       60       NA       NA
> 2: 2016-09-12 00:30:00       NA       NA       29       17
> 3: 2016-09-12 00:45:00       13       48       NA       NA
> 4: 2016-09-12 01:00:00       NA       NA       46       59
> 5: 2016-09-12 01:15:00       NA       NA       NA       NA
> 6: 2016-09-12 01:30:00       13       25       36       51
> ```

#### Using `melt()` and `dcast()`

This approach will work also for more than two data frames to be combined. The individual data chunks are reshaped from wide to long form, combined to a large file which is then reshaped from long to wide format again. Finally, the sequence of time stamps is right joined.

```
rbindlist(lapply(list(df1, df2), melt, id.vars = "D_Time"))[
  , dcast(.SD, D_Time ~ variable)][
    .(seq(min(D_Time), max(D_Time), by = "15 mins")), on = "D_Time"]
```

> ```
>                 D_Time Speed_BT Speed_GT Speed_AA Speed_DD
> 1: 2016-09-12 00:15:00       23       60       NA       NA
> 2: 2016-09-12 00:30:00       NA       NA       29       17
> 3: 2016-09-12 00:45:00       13       48       NA       NA
> 4: 2016-09-12 01:00:00       NA       NA       46       59
> 5: 2016-09-12 01:15:00       NA       NA       NA       NA
> 6: 2016-09-12 01:30:00       13       25       36       51
> ```

#### Data

```
df1 <- readr::read_table(
  "   D_Time                   Speed_BT       Speed_GT
2016-09-12 00:15:00          23            60  
  2016-09-12 00:45:00          13            48  
  2016-09-12 01:30:00          13            25  ")
df2 <- readr::read_table(
  "D_Time                     Speed_AA        Speed_DD
2016-09-12 00:30:00          29            17  
  2016-09-12 01:00:00          46            59  
  2016-09-12 01:30:00          36            51")
```